# How to use "Command" property of a button

Tags: excel, vba, button, click, command

I read that buttons in Excel have a property called "Command" which *"Gets or sets the command to invoke when this button is pressed."*

([See MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.command(v=vs.110).aspx))

However, I can't find any information on how to use it.

Any help?

Comment: Your linked page is from the .NET documentation

Comment: Is there a similar function in vba

Comment: Forms buttons on a worksheet have an "OnAction" property. ActiveX buttons have  `buttonName_click` event handlers.